# How to get particular column in responsive jquery datatable for small Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have implemented responsive jquery datatable in one of my project.
At the end of  each row there is edit/detail link.

If i click edit/detail link:

1)**Large Screen** - It picks the UseID(Which is first Column in a row), so that i can edit that User.

2)**Small Screen** - Because of responsiveness the row will splitted as show below. It doesnot pick that User ID.

**Large Screen Edit/Detail is Last row** 
[image: When the Scree is large.]

**Large Screen after clicking Edit link**
[image: When i click Edit link]

**Small Screen See Edit/detail link which is splitted**
[image: When Image is in Small Screen]

**I am not able to get the UserID alert when i click edit link whenever the screen is small.**

My Code.

```
  <table id="myExample" class="display responsive nowrap">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
         <th>State</th>
        <th>Email</th>
         <th>Edit</th>
       </tr>
</thead>
</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#myExample').DataTable({
                     "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Admin/LoadData",
                        "type": "GET",
                        "datatype": "json"

                    },
                    "columns": [

                        { "data": "Usr_Nm", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "FirstName", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "LastName", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "Street", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "City", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "Zip", "autowidth": true },
                        { "data": "Sate", "autowidth": true },


                        {
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="Edit">Edit</a>/<a href="#" class="Detail">Detail</a>',
                            orderable: false
                        }
                    ]


                });


            $('#myExample').on('click', 'a.Edit', function (e) {


                var UserId = $(this).closest('tr.').find('td').find('.sorting_1').text();


                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Admin/UserEdit',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { 'id': UserId },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        // alert('1:');
                        // alert(response);
                        if (response.isRedirect) {
                            // alert('1');
                            window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
                            //window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
                        }
                        // }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert("Some error");
                    }
                });

            });
     })
    </script>
```

To get UserID:

```
 var UserId = $(this).closest('tr.').find('td').find('.sorting_1').text();
```

Inspect Element in Large Screen
[image: Inspect Element: When the screen is Large]

Inspect Element in Small Screen:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must go through the dataTables API in order to get data for columns not present in the DOM (removed due to responsiveness).

You can get the all values for a certain row by `table.row(<tr-node>).data()` :

```js
$('#myExample').on('click', 'a.Edit', function (e) {
  var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()
  //if it is "User Name" / first column you are after
  var userId = data[0]
  ...
})
```

Comment: I don't know something missing on my code. I tried with this code as well.. please suggest me

Comment: If i do var data = table.row(0).data(). Then it will get the first row data. But it does not get  Index when table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()

Comment: But then you have done something wrong...! Have made a fiddle that demonstrates the above -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dz1Ltqqa/** resize the table so columns is hidden and click on a link. It is using an `<a>` tag and a `.Edit` as in your OP.  I can only guess why it is not working for you, the code you have provided is not extremely informative; you are not using `responsive` in the pasted code yourself (?) and the rest looks like a series of try and errors - are you sure you are using the right code at all ...?

Comment: Hi davidkonrad,  It seems working when the the anchor tag is in the first cloumn when the screen is small. But it does not work  when that particular anchor tag is the last column. I also tested your code in jsfiddle

Comment: I added <td><a href="#" class="Edit">Click</a></td> after the Salary Column in the Jsfiddle and try to click that anchor tag then nothing happen